# Improve performance while updating entities in CRM 4.0 using C#

Tags: c#, performance, coding-style, batch-file, dynamics-crm-4

I have a mass update application that updates the record of a particular entity, by updating some of it's fields based on some logic. I am using TargetUpdate for the record updating because I have a workflow attached to the update of the entity which I don't want to fire (in case I use normal update). But it's taking forever to update those records. Currently it takes around 1.5 hour to update 1K records. In actual scenario, it would need to update around 10K records in a time span of 5-6 hours maximum daily(nightly job). Is there any way I can improve the performance.

```
Centity newentityobect;

newentityobect= new Centity()
{
    asp_field1 = new Key()
    {
        Value = new Guid(field1Value)
    },
    asp_field2 = field2Value,
    asp_field3 = field3Value,
    asp_field3 = field4Value
};

TargetUpdateCentity objx = new TargetUpdateCentity();
objx.Centity = newentityobect;
UpdateRequest updateCentity = new UpdateRequest();
updateCentity.Target = objx;
UpdateResponse updatedCentity = (UpdateResponse)crmUpdateObject.Execute(updateCentity);
```

Above is a small code snippet I am using to update records.

Comment: You're code snippet only shows the update of a single object. How are you running through 1K of em? 1 by 1 or in a multithreaded way? If you do it 1 by 1, have you tried multi treaded or does the service freack out when you do that?

Comment: It's actually the code within a loop. And I haven't tried the multi threading, because there's a high chance that the multi-threaded application might freak out and it will becoming too complicated to debug. Threading is something I always tend to avoid, because generally multi threaded applications have a high chance of freaking out.

Answer (score 0):

Since my explanation would be too long in comment i'll post it as an answer.
I'm aware that multithreading involves more thinking/problems/risks but you're looking at 1 service call that responds too slow to your liking. 
If you want to speed things up there are 4 possibilities :

- do multiple service calls at once(multi threaded)
- edit the service call(which i think you can't because it's a basic crm service)
- use a different service call(i doubt it exists but if there is a bulk update using that would increase your performance)
- avoid the service and edit the database directly(i highly doubt crm supports this so consider it as a hack but you might get a great increase in speed of you update the database directly).

Assuming there is no service call for bulk updates and you cannot edit the service you can either go multi threaded or directly to the database.
Given these 2 choices i would  definatly choose the multi threaded approach, it will be a much safer approach then hacking your way into the database.

Since .NET 4.0 you can easiliy enable multi threading on a list like this :

```
Parallel.ForEach(entityList, entity => {
   //copy paste your looped code here
});
```

You could edit your code and see if the end result is too your liking, if not : welcome to crm, god speed !

Comment: Thank you for the solutions proposed. I would like to repond to your solutions as follows: 1. Multi Threaded - Only available option right now. 2. Edit the service call - Not possible in CRM. 3. Use a different service - Doesn't exist in CRM. 4. Edit the database - Not recommended and has a high risk factor associated with it.

Comment: Something else that crossed my mind : cant you modify and create crm modules inside the crm environment? Maybe you could nest all your code there so that database access is done locally and not through a webservice.